# amcl_omni.launch missing on Hydro (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the navigation stack tutorial and I've noticed that the launch file it mentions for AMCL doesn't actually exist. I looked into the AMCL directory and it's empty, but I can still run the node itself via rosrun.

rosdep says it's okay, and I've tried reinstall via apt-get to no avail. I have installed ROS from the repositories.

The tutorial in question is this one (and section):
(see first link in comment. I don't have enough karma to post the link.)

Particularly, this line:

```
<include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_omni.launch" />
```

When launching, it gives the following error:

```
while processing /home/knifa/HexapodKit/ROS/src/hexapod/launch/hexapod_nav.launch:
while processing /opt/ros/hydro/share/amcl/examples/amcl_omni.launch:
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/hydro/share/amcl/examples/amcl_omni.launch'
```

Looking into the AMCL directory only shows the following files:

```
knifa@ubuntu:/opt/ros/hydro/share/amcl$ rosls amcl
    cmake  
    package.xml
```

I am expecting to find this file, which is on the navigation git repository:
(see second link in comment. I don't have enough karma to post the link.)

The binary for AMCL itself is still available in the /lib folder.

```
knifa@ubuntu:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/amcl$ ls
    amcl
```

Any ideas why it isn't there already? Should I just copy it from the repository?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117886/amcl_omni.launch-missing-on-hydro-(ubuntu-12.04)/) by [Knifa](https://answers.ros.org/users/10851/knifa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-01-14**:
Please actually show what files your looking for and how with the error messages you're receiving.

**Comment by [Knifa](https://answers.ros.org/users/10851/knifa/) on 2014-01-15**:
I've edited my post now. I don't have enough karma to link the tutorial and files I'm expecting to find.

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Creating_a_Launch_File_for_the_Navigation_Stack

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/amcl/examples/amcl_omni.launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like that file is not installed in the hydro version of AMCL. I expect that it was forgotten to be installed in the upgrade. I suggest you file a ticket here: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/new

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2